# Installing Itunes on PlayOnlinux with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, playonlinux, itunes

I've had no luck installing Itunes 10 via PlayOnlinux.
When installing the iTunes application following a guide via [Ubuntu Desktop for Beginners: iTunes setup on Ubuntu - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jrJVEpV6Vi0&t=5s) I get far enough to installing the program. But somewhere along the installation proces, iTunes get a failure and stops.

I've been thinking if it is my LTS version which is the curse or even my pc old can't cope. I really don't know: maybe it's the wine not working as it should?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out everything i needed to know... PlayOnlinux is a pure waste wine (Staging) is the way to go...
latest Itunes 12 installed and running perfectly!
[LINUX
Wine Programs Not Working? Try These Steps](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/wine-programs-not-working-try-steps/)